# Is there a source code analysis tool, which facilitates assisted navigation in both space and time?

Tags: open-source, git, code-analysis, code-review

In the good ol' days, **source navigator** often came to the rescue for going through big chunks of code (hello to x-users of the tool and thank you RedHat!). Lots of things changed since then and new tools have appeared, however I have a pending question in relation to code analysis and assisted code navigation:

- Is there a tool that can function well in both **space** (across complete LoC and hopefully across *multiple git repositories*) as well as **time** (i.e. navigate easily *through commits & tags*)?
- If so, is said tool configurable enough so that the whole navigation experience can be mapped on, say, *modifiers+arrow keys only*?
- Extra bonus points if it could analyse many languages, beyond C or Python, or it is an established IDE with further integrations etc.
- Open source, please.

As an example, try to imagine exploring this codebase with its sub-repos as a first-timer, as well as a 3rd-party-provided helm chart:

- https://github.com/zabbix

Can we do better than downloading all repos, checking out commits, and `grep -R` through them?

At the moment, what is often found convenient is a search via an organisation's github page when it exists, to identify where individual functions, variables or constants are defined, with recursive grep as second best - but the need to search and navigate through *timeline of commits* is still not served in an ideal way.

In assisted code navigation, it should be relatively easy to detect how fi. a `db` configuration parameter is being used, where and how and what is the first thing to break if it gets modified:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - apiversion: v1
    kind: Secret
    type: Opaque
    metadata:
      name: {{ template "fullname" . }}-db-secret
    data:
      db-root-pass: "myotherpassword"
      db-zbx-user: "hello"
      db-zbx-pass: "world"
```

I expect to see a tool, or a list of tools, that others declare content with their level of functionality, as regards the summary stated above and the need for *assisted code navigation* in both space/time.

p.s. 
Ideally the tool should be robust and flexible enough, so that exploring f.i. linux kernel function's `netif_receive_skb_core`'s calling graph should be painless and intuitive, *across commits* and different kernel versions.

Comment: A colleague offered: GitLens is an open-source extension for Visual Studio Code.
ref. https://gitlens.amod.io/